# Pattern matching list vs tuple python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
tpl = (1, 2, 3)
for i in [lst, tpl]:
  match i:
    case [1, 2, 3]: print('list', i, type(i))
    case (1, 2, 3): print('tuple', i, type(i))
```

outputs,

```
list [1, 2, 3] <class 'list'>
list (1, 2, 3) <class 'tuple'>
```

it considers `tuple` as a `list`, and matches `(1, 2, 3)` with `[1, 2, 3]`

???

Comment: maybe change order of cases

Comment: then it considers both as tuple

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a specific question?

Comment: then you may have to check also type - `ininstance(i, tuple)`

Comment: now there is no dictionary part

Comment: Literal patterns do not include lists and tuples, as there is technically no such thing as a list or tuple literal. `[1,2,3]` and `(1,2,3)` are both examples of the same *sequence* pattern.

Comment: See [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#sequence-patterns).

Comment: I think so I should just use `list((1, 2, 3))` and `tuple((1, 2, 3))`